# Error while changing hostname inside docker container

Tags: docker, centos, ansible, travis-ci

I am trying to change the hostname of a docker container running centos using the command

```
hostnamectl set-hostname test.ovirt.org
```

But it gives me back a traceback of

```
Could not set property: Failed to execute program /lib64/dbus-1/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
```

with an exit code of 1.

Here is the relevant travis-CI build traceback

- https://travis-ci.org/rhevm-qe-automation/ovirt-ansible/jobs/242733186#L6181-L6210

**EDIT**:

I am running the command to change the hostname inside an ansible task inside Travis build. Editing the hostname using an interactive mode wouldn't be an option.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to **name the container as per your requirement you can make use of argument --hostname** while running the container.

```
# docker run --hostname=my-server -it ubuntu:15.0 /bin/bash
root@my-server:/# hostname
my-server
root@my-server:/#
```

EDIT1 : As you need to change during the runtime, **container needs to have root privileges to change the hostname**. By default Docker containers will have limited root permissions.

When you try to change the hostname following error may occur saying that you should have root permissions:

```
# docker run -it ubuntu:15.0 /bin/bash
root@92b712251220:/# hostname
92b712251220
root@92b712251220:/# hostname new-server
hostname: you must be root to change the host name
root@92b712251220:/#
```

When you **run the same container with --privileged option** which means running the container with all the root privileges, you will be able to change the hostname:

```
# docker run -it --privileged ubuntu:15.0 /bin/bash
root@08c70ab0c9e3:/# hostname new-server
root@08c70ab0c9e3:/# hostname
new-server
root@08c70ab0c9e3:/#
```

**Ideally it is not the best practise to run the container with --privileged option which gives full control of host machine which is not secured.**

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer but I was looking for a way in which I would be able to change the hostname at runtime while running the ansible playbook

Comment: can you check now, by trying with --privileged option as explained in the answer.

Comment: Hey there, edited the question details a little to provide clarity as I cannot use the interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable the `SYS_ADMIN` [runtime privilege and capability](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities)